# Can Uber drivers deduct daily car washes on their income tax?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

Imagine a person who drives for Uber every day. Before driving passengers, he takes his car to the car wash to be washed. Is the cost of the car wash deductible on the person's income tax?

I am thinking it is, unless the person takes the standard mileage deduction. If he does then the cost is not deductible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expenses are only deductible to the extent that they're *ordinary* and *necessary* (See the [IRC Sec. 162(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/162)).

What is "ordinary" and what is "necessary"? The [IRS Taxpayer Advocate says this](https://www.taxpayeradvocate.irs.gov/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/2013-ARC_VOL-1_S3_MLI-2.pdf):

> ... The Supreme Court describes an “ordinary” expense as customary or usual and of common or frequent occurrence in the taxpayer’s trade or business. The Court describes a “necessary” expense as one that is appropriate and helpful for development of the business. ...
>
> ... Common law also requires that in addition to being ordinary and necessary, the amount of the expense must be reasonable for the expense to be deductible. ...

As usual, in the end it comes to facts and circumstances. Can you prove that this expense is both ordinary and necessary, and the amounts are reasonable to the expense? If not - then no, you cannot deduct it.

In case of standard mileage deduction it's a moot point since all the vehicle related expenses are included in it.

Comment: I think the T&C for Uber driver is to keep a clean car. Probably can ask Uber about it.

Comment: @Nelson how F&C matter: if you live in an area with frequent rains and dirty roads, it may be ordinary and necessary. If you live in an area with clean air and blue skies all day long - do you really need to wash the car every morning? Consider, say, Irvine, CA in August compared to Rochester, NY in November.